# How do I prevent two divs from jumping around my webpage when it first loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading

Thanks for trying to help!  I'm having an issue with the following code when the page initially loads.  The div class 'highlights', which contains the divs 'box' and 'box-2', jumps around the page when loading.  I suspect is has something to do with the social media buttons running javascript above the divs but cannot figure out how to get everything to stay still.  Here is a link to the [site](http://powerrankingsguru.com/MLB/2015-MLB-power-rankings/week-18.html).  Thank you all for helping!!

```
<div class="buttons">

    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.powerrankingsguru.com/MLB/2015-MLB-                          power-rankings/week-18.html" data-layout="button_count">
    </div>

    <div class="twitter-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
     <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)                                                       [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))                                       {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
     </div>

    <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="bubble" data-                                            href="http://www.powerrankingsguru.com/MLB/2015-MLB-power-rankings/week-18.html">             </div>    

</div>        

<div class="highlights">    
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header"><p>What to Watch</p></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <div class="game-details">
                    </div>
                    <div class="game-overview">
                        <div class="away-team">
                            <div class="away-team-logo">
                                <img src="../../Images/MLB/Los_Angeles_Dodgers_75px.gif">
                            </div>
                                <div class="record">
                                    <h6>Dodgers</h6>
                                    <h6 class="lighter">(60-45)</h6>
                                </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="home-team">
                            <div class="home-team-logo">
                                <img src="../../Images/MLB/Pittsburgh_Pirates_75px.gif">
                            </div>
                            <div class="record">
                                <h6>Pirates</h6>
                                <h6 class="lighter">(61-43)</h6>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="symbol">@</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                        <div class="date"> 
                            <h4><span class="left">Fri Aug 7th - Sun Aug 9th</span></h4>
                        </div>    
        </div>

        <div class="box2">
            <div class="box2-header"><p>Biggest Movers</p></div>
                <div class="rise">   
                    <div class="rise-up"><img src=../../Images/arrowGW.gif></div>
                    <div class="rise-number"><p>5</p></div>
                    <div class="rise-team"><img src="../../Images/MLB/Toronto_Blue_Jays_75px.gif"></div>      
                </div>
                <div class="fall">
                    <div class="fall-down"><img src=../../Images/arrowRW.gif></div>
                    <div class="fall-number"><p>5</p></div>
                    <div class="fall-team"><img src="../../Images/MLB/Atlanta_Braves_75px.gif"></div>
                </div>    
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like, because the boxes are all floating left, they're trying to fill the space where the social media buttons are, but then running out of space and going down to the next line once the media buttons actually load in. Try giving div.buttons the css attribute `clear:both;` so that the boxes are forced to be below the social media buttons, regardless of whether or not they've loaded.

Comment: If you know the sizes of all the img files, just let the HTML know about those sizes. By the way, are you sure about the hrefs with all the spaces in them?

Comment: I would not worry about it so much. From previous A/B tests and user test groups at previous employers, I've seen no significant ROI difference between cloaked and non-cloaked pages. One user I specifically recall mentioning she liked knowing when the page was loading and when it was finished, like when the page would "build itself" as she mentioned (nodes jumping on the screen and shifting). Now that's one user's opinion but regardless you could be wasting a lot of time pleasing only yourself here. Just a heads up.

Comment: @oxguy3 - this didn't seem to work but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @MrLister - this is my first post to stackoverflow...I may have mangled the hrefs when trying to format the code properly for the post :) ... I'm not familiar with putting the size of an image into the HTML.  How do I go about doing that?  Thanks!!

Comment: @AlienWebguy - I find that interesting Alien, thanks for sharing!  It bothers me, because it seems unprofessional, but hey, if it doesn't matter to most I can live with it.  Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using javascript you could hide your container box with `display: hidden` and then in a javascript `onload` function you would set the display back to `block`.

Div:

```
<div id="highlightDiv" class="highlights" style="display: hidden">
    ...
</div>
```

onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("highlightDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Ryan - thanks for the tip...but I'm not comfortable using Javascript quite yet!  Appreciate the help anyways...cheers!